# UINavigationController change position of pushed UIViewController view

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, view, position, uinavigationbar, offset

I tried to solve this in so many ways but always failed.

Basically what I need is a NavigationController with a customized NavigationBar (different height and smaller back Button) which I already achieved.

This creats two problems. If I use the default NavigationBar of the NavigationController, I have a smaller NavigationBar but the views of the pushed ViewControllers still position as if the NavBar would have the usual height. If on the other hand I use my a self created NavBar and hide the default one, then the views of the pushed ViewControllers position as if I wouldn't have any NavBar at all. I don't know where to set the views frame. No matter where I try to set them, it doesn't work.

Is there any strategy without implementing an own NavigationController from scratch?

Not using nib files, dev for iphone OS 4.0 but will switch back to iphone OS 3 quite soon again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your own customized Navigation controller and setting the frame of the pushed view in its `ViewWillAppear` method.

Hiding the usual Navigation Controller will create problems. Its better NOT to use it completely if you do not intend to use it . But after doing that , you will have to use your customized Navigation controller in the project wheresoever.